# mysql returning the lowest column value in GROUP BY query

Tags: php, mysql

I've been using this query in a program for quite some time now but it has started giving me the wrong result. I am expecting to return one column name per unique LEVEL and then the lowest z_index value found in that level.

```
SELECT * FROM Conrad WHERE ProductID = '1' GROUP BY level ORDER BY z_index
```

It used to return something like this:

```
ProductID    level    z_index
==============================
   1          One       10
   1          Two       20
   1          Three     30
```

That is the expected result. But it is now returning this:

```
ProductID    level    z_index
==============================
   1          One       83
   1          Two       224
   1          Three     308
```

I still get one per level but it is now returning any z_index value found for that level.

Did something change in MySql or has my query been bad forever?

**Update Saturday January 21:** Now when I add in more column names that I will need the query returns the correct values for the z_index but the values of file_name and file_loc seem to be from the first row of the level and not of the row that contains the correct z_index value.

What caused that to happen?

```
SELECT ProductID, level, min(z_index), file_name, file_loc FROM Conrad WHERE ProductID = '1' GROUP BY level ORDER BY z_index

ProductID    level    z_index   file_name   file_loc
====================================================
   1          One       10        wrong.png    ?
   1          Two       20        file.png     ?
   1          Three     30        names.png    ?
```

Comment: Your query was bad forever. As is well documented.

Comment: If you use GROUP BY, use a aggregate function ( http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_functions.asp) like min(z_index)

Comment: Also, it looks a little like z_index is a string

Comment: z_index column is int(4)

Comment: The (4) is meaningless in this context. But reza's query will return the correct value - unless you've omitted some information.

Comment: @user1601513 Where two respondents both provide exactly the same answer, it's good form to 'accept' the first respondent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
  productid,
  level,
  min(z_index)
from
  Conrad 
WHERE 
  ProductID = '1' 
GROUP BY 
  level 
ORDER BY z_index
```

Comment: This query works perfectly. I suspect that my original query got lucky by what the natural order of the table was long ago. Thanks!

Comment: @user1601513, are the numbers from this different?

Answer (score 2):

your query is little wrong for minimum value. try following query

```
SELECT ProductID
     , level
     , MIN(z_index) z_index
  FROM Conrad 
 WHERE ProductID = 1
 GROUP 
    BY ProductID
     , level 
 ORDER 
    BY z_index
```

Comment: can you please show me please... its showing me no wrong.

Comment: The original poster didn't say anything about that. He answered the question.

Comment: in that case you also have to group by productid. that i thought is not required here.

Comment: lolz. so for future modification that might take place for this project, you said current query is wrong... can not argue with this logic but still feels its harsh judgement.